# inputType not working in EditTextPreference when using support preference fragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

in EditTextPreference inputType attribute is not working when i am using support library for preference.

the version of support library i am using

> com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1

but inputType seems to work when I am using preference Fragment 
can someone explain it why?

here is the code for EditTextPreference

```
  <EditTextPreference
            android:id="@+id/computer_ip"
            android:defaultValue="192.168.0.103"
            android:hint="Computer Ip"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:key="@string/computerIp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:title="Computer Ip" />
```

as in this code the inputType is numberDecimal when support library is usedthe numberDecimal doesn't have any effect on the keyboard instead it shows the keyboard with all alphabets.

Comment: Information is not enough. Add your relevant code and elaborate more about **attribute is not working**

Comment: I've just run into the same issue. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: Same here using androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha01

Comment: So apparently this is a known issue, which really hasn't been resolved yet (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37060038). I ended up using this library, which fixes the issues and works great, see https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution, just use

```
EditTextPreference preference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("key");
EditText et = preference.getEditText();
if (et != null) {
    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    //in fact, you can do whatever you can normally with an EditText here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add custom layout and specify EditText with android:inputType="number"

```
<android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference
            android:dialogLayout="@layout/preference_dialog_edittext_custom"
```

So that you may copy original preference_dialog_layout.xml file and edit it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/message"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@android:id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp" />

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            EditTextPreference numberPref = findPreference(STR_PREF_KEY_JANK_THRESHOLD);
        //https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings#customize_an_edittextpreference_dialog
        numberPref.setOnBindEditTextListener(
                editText -> editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER));
```